# Grails: Why "g:if" around fields in show template?

Tags: grails-2.0

The default show template places an g:if test="${domainInstance?.fieldName}" around each domain class field.  The problem is that Boolean fields which have a 'false' value are not displayed on the page.  What is the purpose of the g:if test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use the g:if option to check if a field is null to avoid null pointer exceptions. You are right though that for a Boolean field that is not null but has a value of false this would return false. I feels a bit like a "feature" of the scaffolding that grails does.

Comment: I think the intention was to test for NULL, but instead they also exclude Boolean.FALSE values.  Maybe I should file a bug report...

Comment: This does sound like the right place for a bug report. If you do they would at least clarify if this is a bug or a feature